# GitLab Extension in AzureDevOps pipeline: "git exe not found. Ensure its installed and in the path"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, gitlab, azure-pipelines

We want to clone a repository from GitLab with [GitLab Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onlyutkarsh.gitlab-integration) in our Azure Release Pipeline. So we have installed [GitLab Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onlyutkarsh.gitlab-integration) in AzureDevOps. Our Agent is an Windows Machine, onPrem.

We have installed Git on the agent (onPrem Windows Machine) which is available via the path: C:\agent\externals\git\cmd\git.exe

Git is a global available and accessible via the cmd, because it is added as an environment variable.

We have added the path to Git to the pipeline variables:

[image]

We use the GitLab Extensions in our Azure DevOps release pipeline to clone repositories. But when we start the pipeline, then we get the following message:

[image]

In the pipeline variables, we tried the following values for Git with no success:

- C:\agent\externals\git\cmd\git.exe
- C:\agent\externals\git\cmd

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevOps doesn't invoke the git from variables.

Please make sure the `git` path has been added to the agent machine Path environment, and in DevOps agent `capabilities` it can list the path, so that it can be invoked. You can follow below steps:

1. On the Windows DevOps agent, you can install the [git for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/), `restart` your windows machine and start the devops agent, it will rescan the capabilities of the agent.
2. On DevOps agent pool, you can confirm the git path has been added  in the **Capabilities**(Project setting-> Agent Pool -> Target agent-> Capabilities):
   [image]
3. Then the git can be used:

[image]

Comment: Restarting the agent has solved the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @Simon, glad to know it helps! Could you please help to mark the answer as it's resolved? Or please let me know if you still have any queries, thanks.